# Rowspan and colspan not proper in table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created table but its not created as I want. I am using bootstrap. I am created table with **row-span and col-span**. I am created nearly same but some of rows are not displayed

I am attaching image for the reference.[image]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class ="table table-bordered" >
  <tr>
    <th> 8</th>
    <th >8 </th>
    <th> 8</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> 8</td>
    <td> 8</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: when coding html tables a lot of help is available online e.g. [html table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables) which allows you to visually design the table and get the code behind. As far as answer to your question is concerned see this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/beyond2013/pen/NVEOaN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**please try this code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  
  </head>
 <body>
   <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class ="table table-bordered" >
  
  <tr>
    <th>8</th>
    <th>8</th>
    <th  colspan="2">8</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td >8</td>
    <td >8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >8</td>
    <td >8</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
   
   
 </body>
</head>  
</html>
```